# Download submitted sitemap from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

Is there any built-in API from Google Webmaster Tools that allows the user to download a sitemap that was previously submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sitemaps: list](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sitemaps/list) to list all the submitted sitemaps. This returns a list of sitemaps with URLs that you can then download.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/siteUrl/sitemaps
                                                   └──┬──┘
           the domain URL e.g. https://example.com/ ──┘
```

You'll need to [authorise first](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/authorizing).